# wpf itemscontrol datatemplate margin

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, itemtemplate

Don't mind the left and right sidebars, they are only temporary till I made proper ones.

As you can see in the code below, and the Image I'm listing all my artists (coming from observablecollection) in a datatemplate.

My question is: How would I make it, so that either the images grow larger upon resizing my gui, or that more margin gets added. Because right now, on the right hand side there is either no space (which I want) or too much space.
I do know why this happens, new item not big small enough to get added so it gets added on the next row. But I don't really know how to solve this in my code.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.DataContext>
            <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding DataContext.Artists, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
        </ItemsControl.DataContext>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!--<v:SingleArtistUC Artist="{Binding}" Background="{StaticResource color_bgelements}"/>-->
                <Grid Width="120" Margin="10" Background="{StaticResource color_bgelements}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.PlayArtistCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ArtistButtonImage}">
                        <ContentControl>
                            <Grid>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ImageByteConv}}" Height="120" Width="120" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                                <Image Source="..\Resources\Images\noimage.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Style="{StaticResource ArtistButtonImageHover}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </Button>

                    <!--<Image Source="..\Resources\Images\noimage.png" Height="120" Width="120" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>-->
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist.ArtistName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" FontSize="12" TextAlignment="Center"/>-->
                        <!--<TextBlock Text="ik wil graag twee lijntjes tekst" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,10,0,5" FontSize="12" TextAlignment="Center"/>-->

                        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.ViewArtistDetailCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Background="{StaticResource color_bgbutton}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,10,0,5" Grid.Row="0">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArtistName}" Style="{StaticResource TextInfo}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Button>
                        <!-- <Button Command="{Binding CMDPlayArtist, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" Tag="{Binding Artist.ID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" Content="Play" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5,0,5" Style="{StaticResource TransButton}"/>-->
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Here how it should always be

[image: How it should be]

how it is when resizing to wrong ratio

[image: when resizing]

Comment: I would leave it how it is, it looks fine. Groove Music in Windows 10 looks the same as do all other tiled wrap panel applications I know of. The user will probably resize the Window to fit more/less tiles on the screen, so having the tiles resize would just be annoying.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, yep, I suck at designing so I'm actually picking colors / formats from excisting players. This is only a project I do in my spare time when I'm bored. Anyway, I was thinking the same thing about resizing the tiles, that it would be a bit annoying. But I do want to get rid of black bar between the last column and the scrollbar. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think its ok, I would leave it. Maybe take a look at Groove Music on Windows 10, which also has a blank space on the right side and then maybe you will feel better about it...